# Error while trying to run docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  terrad:
    image: terramoney/localterra-core:bombay
    pull_policy: always
    volumes:
      - ./config:/root/.terra/config
    networks:
      - terra
    ports:
      - "26657:26657"
      - "1317:1317"
      - "9090:9090"
      - "9091:9091"
    command: terrad start
  oracle:
    image: terramoney/pseudo-feeder:bombay
    pull_policy: always
    depends_on:
      - terrad
    networks:
      - terra
    environment:
      TESTNET_LCD_URL: http://terrad:1317
    command: start
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - terra
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev
  # redis:
  #   image: redis:latest
  #   networks:
  #     - terra
  #   ports:
  #     - "6379:6379"
  fcd-collector:
    image: terramoney/fcd:1.0.0-beta.2
    depends_on:
      - terrad
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    networks:
      - terra
    env_file: fcd.env
    command: collector
    restart: unless-stopped
  fcd-api:
    image: terramoney/fcd:1.0.0-beta.2
    depends_on:
      - terrad
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    networks:
      - terra
    ports:
      - 3060:3060
    env_file: fcd.env
    command: start

networks:
  terra:
    driver: bridge
```

when trying to run docker-compose up I am facing this error:
My docker-compose version is 2.1.1

I got this error
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dlocalterra%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=0": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: Are you running from root user ? If running from non-root user then does your user is added in docker group ?

Comment: I am running it in wsl .. and I think non root user

Comment: Not sure about windows but if you are running in unix then https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/ will resolve your issue.

Comment: sudo docker-compose up solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `pull_policy` to `false`. The allowed values are `always`, `never`, `missing` or `build`. You can also keep it empty.

[Docs are here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#pull_policy).

Comment: I changed it now I am getting different error.